# Ruby On Rails - CRUD - Destroy/Delete Not Working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, turbo

I've gone through a good chunk of this tutorial, and have gotten to the part where functionality for deleting articles is added:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

...but whenever the 'Delete' link is clicked on, the article is not deleted.  Nothing happens, and a GET request is sent rather than a DELETE.

From the erb file:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(@article), data:{
  turbo_method: :delete,
  turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'
} %>
```

From the controller:

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
end
```

After trying a solution that was mentioned in SO and in various Web pages (adding the below to my 'application.html.erb' file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

...I get this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

I did some digging and realized that the application scaffolder (`rails new blog` in this case) didn't create any Javascript directories much less add any JS files to them.  I'm  fine with adding them myself, but I don't even know what JS files Rails and/or Turbo is looking for.  JQuery? Some other library?

Ideally, however, I'd like to know how to properly scaffold an app so that any necessary Javascript is included.

Thanks,
Bryan

***EDIT***
I was able to get the delete functionality working by using the 'non-turbo' method of deleting items and using 'button_to' instead of 'link_to' for the 'Delete' link.  However-- I would still like to know why the app as shown in the tutorial doesn't work as expected, and how to use a link rather than a button to trigger the item deletion (not to mention why using turbo doesn't work).

Comment: Did you build your assets? Usually `bin/dev` to start processes with foreman

Comment: There is no 'bin/dev' directory or executable in my project.

Comment: Probably you had some error during application creation. So your app was not created completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my answer is that there is no answer--- but I believe mechnicov is correct in saying that the app was not created correctly; I recreated the project in Linux, and everything works as expected.  Apparently there is something wrong with my Ruby/Rails installation in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered the same problem following the official documentation.
And after doing hours of research, I managed to make the turbo functionality works just by adding this line in `application.html.erb`.

`<%= javascript_include_tag "turbo", type: "module" %>`

To be honest, I did not understand why this is working, and I am not 100% sure whether this is the correct way to use turbo in rails 7.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32004442)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working!

Somewhere along the way of me trying things, I stumbled upon mention of the `turbo-rails` gem. I found a working solution with these pieces:

1. Add this in the `application.html.erb` file:

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "turbo", type: "module" %>
   ```
2. Add `gem "turbo-rails", "~> 1.0"` to your Gemfile
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Run `bin/rails turbo:install`
   Note: not sure if this last step is necessary, but I was following instructions from [here](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails)

Using these steps, the code from the rails guide works, along with the confirmation dialog.